# What is MIME type of Google drive spreadsheet?

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a demo for create google drive Spreadsheet...please tell me that which MIME type used for Spreadsheet.

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // write content to DriveContents
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            try {
                writer.write("Google Drive SpreadSheet");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Android Demo")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setStarred(true).build();

            // create a file on root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
        }
    }.start();
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The following table lists MIME types that are specific to Google Apps and Google Drive.
[image]

it can be found here: [Supported MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types)

For Google drive sheet i think you are looking at `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`

Comment: @ DalmTo...Thanks for response..but its not working in my code.

Comment: @AlpaMori , did you find a solution to this problem. Coz I also have the same problem at my end